# python OrderedDict get a key index of

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, ordereddictionary

Can `OrderedDict` get a key position?

is like `list` of `index()`

```
test = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
test.index('b') # return 1
```

Comment: Python 3.6 dict is ordered and should be able to perform this operation as O(1)

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, Can you explain how this is possible with O(1) complexity? All answer below use `list.index` (or, `next` with a generator expression).

Comment: @jpp The compact dict introduced in 3.6 has a data structure that supports this. But I can't explain that data structure in a comment. You'll need to read up about it.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, Ah yes I have read up on the structure, but as far as I'm aware the O(1) complexity only materializes after a *one-off* O(n) process to construct a mapping dictionary like `{v: k for k, v in enumerate(d)}`. This mapping (as far as I know) isn't stored anywhere accessible in Python.

Comment: @jpp I don't think that this information is available if you have a Python dict to hand, that wasn't clear. I think my point is more that the data structure supports O(1) `index()` if it were to be implemented. I can see that my original comment was not even remotely close to expressing that though!  :-(

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, Understood. And, agreed, this is the kind of functionality which should be available "for free" with the new by-default insertion-ordered `dict` structure in 3.6.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

just one line program.
such as:

```
print(list(your_ordered_dict).index('your_key'))
```

Maybe you can use `lambda`,like this line program:

```
f = lambda ordered_dict, key: list(ordered_dict).index(key)
```

Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

Keep it simple.

```
from collections import OrderedDict

x = OrderedDict('test1'='a', 'test2'='b')
print(list(x.keys().index('test1'))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can write this in two ways:

- `list(x).index('b')`
- `next(i for i, k in enumerate(x) if k=='b')`

The first one will be a little faster for small dicts, but a lot slower, and waste a lot of space, for huge ones. (Of course most of the time, `OrderedDict`s are pretty small.)

Both versions will work for *any* iterable; there's nothing special about `OrderedDict` here.

Answer (score 0):

If you take the keys as a list, you can then index like:

#### Code:

```
list(x).index('b')
```

#### Test Code:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

x = OrderedDict(a=1, b=2)
print(list(x).index('b'))
```

#### Results:

```
1
```

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer `list(x).index('b')` will be `O(N)` every time you're searching for the position.

Instead, you can create a mapping key -> position which will be `O(1)` once the mapping is constructed.

```py
ordered_dict = OrderedDict(a='', b='')

key_to_pos = {k: pos for pos, k in enumerate(ordered_dict)}
assert key_to_pos['b'] == 1
```